# All my HTML tags that use FontAwesome seem to some have aria-hidden="true" added to them. How is this happening?

Tags: c#, bootstrap-4, webforms, font-awesome

I'm currently using Bootstrap 4 and FontAwesome on my website.  I'm working on ADA compliance now.

The crazy thing is that it seems that every HTML tag that uses FontAwesome somehow gets aria-hidden="true" added to it.  Is this by default?  How do I prevent this from occurring?

I've looked through to see if I can find that being added on any JavaScript files, but I'm not seeing anything.

It's fine that the  tags get it, but not the anchor tags.

Comment: Are you using the Font Awesome CDN? If so, is it set with auto-accessibility enabled? https://cdn.fontawesome.com/help#qa-autoa11y

Comment: @AdamG Yes, I'm using the CDN. So, do I just not use the CDN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the CDN, it's possible that the [auto-accessibility option](https://cdn.fontawesome.com/help#qa-autoa11y) is enabled, which is designed to automatically inject the `aria-hidden` tags for you.

> https://cdn.fontawesome.com/help#qa-autoa11y
>
> If enabled as a feature in your embed code, Font Awesome CDN will try
> to identify [accessibility scenarios] in your UI as well as provide the
> modern and proper syntax assistive technologies recognize. For icons
> that have semantic or interactive meaning, this means you'll need to
> provide a proper text alternative to be used.

Log into your Font Awesome kit, choose the **Settings** tab, and confirm that the checkbox for **Auto-Accessibility** is unchecked under the **Features** section.

Comment: Thank you SO very much.  I suspected it had to do with FontAwesome, but it had been so long since I set that up that I couldn't remember.  Thank you!!!

Comment: No problem! If you don’t need to exert full control over it yourself due to internal code compliance reasons and you’d like Font Awesome to continue injecting accessibility tags for most content, you may also be able to supply your own `title` attribute, which will indicate that the usage has semantic meaning and should not be hidden by screen readers.